# getting javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException in jaxrs

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am getting an javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException when giving xml with multiple element tags. My JAXB annotated class is like the one below.

```
@XmlRootElement
    public class Group {

        private String id;
        private String name;

        @XmlElementWrapper(name="groups")
        @XmlElement(name="group")
        private ArrayList<Group> grouplist;

        public void setGrouplist(ArrayList<Group> grouplist){
            this.grouplist=grouplist;
        }

        public ArrayList<Group> getGrouplist(){
            return grouplist;
        }
           ---------------------------
           ---------------------------
           -------------------------
```

The input xml will be like this....

```
<groups>
<group>
<id>1</id>
<name>asd</name>
<designation>SE</designation>
</group>
</groups>
```

My resource is like this.

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)    
 public Response addGroup(@Context HttpServletRequest req)throws JAXBException,IOException{
 JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(Group.class);
 Group grps= (Group)jaxb.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(req.getInputStream());
```

When I give the above xml from the req I am getting the below exception

```
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"groups"). Expected elements are <{}group>: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"groups"). Expected elements are <{}group>
```

The above is working fine when i give one group in my xml by removing the groups tag and the corresponding @xmlelementWrapper arraylist.

Comment: You might get more interest in your question if you accept some answers to other questions you have posed.

Comment: @DaveRlz I have accepted the answers..:).Can anyone answer to my question plz....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a root element in your class. Change it to be:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Group {
...
...
```

Comment: I have declared the root element also. I think the problem might be with the resource. Because the same is working fine when i give single group in xml. can u check the error msg I am getting which is mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this while using Apache CXF's JAX-RS 2.0 client, you may be hitting [CXF-5980](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5980).